# Php code working on local server but giving syntax error on live server

Tags: codeigniter

Code:

```
function getUserId($userName) {

    $myModel = new MY_Model();
    $requiredFields = "id";
    $whereClause = [  // line number 35
        "is_active" => 'ACTIVE',
        "user_name" => $userName
    ];
    $userId = $myModel->select("users", $requiredFields, $whereClause);
    return $userId;
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /home/com/public_html/_apis/application/helpers/custom_helper.php on line 35
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '['

Filename: helpers/custom_helper.php

Line Number: 35

Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 1):

**Replace Where Clause with this** (Hope this help) :

```
  $whereClause = array(  // line number 35
       "is_active" => 'ACTIVE',
       "user_name" => $userName
  );
```

Comment: What is the reason and why it's working on local but not on live plus i have written all the code and i don't want to change it everywhere. On live server the php version is same as the local.

Comment: so what is output of your query and tell me ur php version

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$whereClause = array();
$whereClause['is_active'] = 'ACTIVE';
$whereClause['user_name'] = $userName;
```